# SQL merge results from multiple joined tables into a single view field (without union)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to merge/combine the results from multiple joined tables into a single field?

**Two key details:**

- Must not use a Union.
- Must be able to generate a View with the code.

We have a nested table structure and there's quite a bit of conditional logic, so I'd like to avoid writing the same large query multiple times (hence why I'm trying to avoid a Union).

```
select [Combine Id results from all 4 tables]
from Table1 tbl1
inner join Table2 tbl2 on tbl1.Id = tbl2.ParentId
inner join Table3 tbl3 on tbl2.Id = tbl3.ParentId
inner join Table4 tbl4 on tbl3.Id = tbl4.ParentId
```

So if the tables contain the following data:

```
Table 1
Id, ParentId
1, 1

Table 2
Id, ParentId
2, 1

Table 3
Id, ParentId
3, 2

Table 4
Id, ParentId
4, 3
```

Is it possible to produce the following single-field output (list of integers) using the join structure from my original query?:

```
Id
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `apply` does what you want:

```
select v.id
from Table1 tbl1 inner join
     Table2 tbl2
     on tbl1.Id = tbl2.ParentId inner join
     Table3 tbl3
     on tbl2.Id = tbl3.ParentId inner join
     Table4 tbl4
     on tbl3.Id = tbl4.ParentId cross apply
     (values (tbl1.id), (tbl2.id), (tbl3.id), (tbl4.id)) v(id);
```

Comment: I was checking to see how will work but got sintaxis error here https://rextester.com/KBBM88215

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . The `values()` list was missing a comma.

Comment: Sql demo: https://rextester.com/VRJT97711 is working. But still don't understand how cross apply works :/

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . It is technically called a lateral join (in case that helps).  If you are learning about then, then it is basically a correlated subquery on steriods -- it can return multiple columns and multiple rows.